# how can i make a TCheckbox without transparent text (ie: it ignores themes)?

Tags: delphi, themes

how can i make a TCheckbox without transparent text (ie: it ignores themes)?  i've been asked to do something unconventional--put a checkbox on the place of the caption of a group box.

in XP, it doesn't look very good.

[image: with xp themes]
<sub>(source: [xrw.bc.ca](http://xrw.bc.ca/download/so/checkboxwithxptheme.png))</sub>

next, i thought i'd try SetWindowTheme(CheckBox1.Handle, ' ', ' ') i'd heard about on the internet.  then you get a white background but it won't paint with the color of the control.

[image: no theme]
<sub>(source: [xrw.bc.ca](http://xrw.bc.ca/download/so/checkboxwithnotheme.png))</sub>

how can we do this?

thank you!
mp

Comment: What version of Delphi?  Using Delphi 6 with the Themes package active, I get the behavior that you desire without any extra consideration.

Comment: Scott, Delphi 6 doesn't support themes natively, so you have to use Mike Lischke's theme library, where I recall group boxes being treated particularly specially. Other questions from this person suggest he's using Delphi 2009. It's apples to oranges.

Comment: thank you for your answers!  rob's correct; i'm using delphi 2009.

Comment: Rob, thanks for clarifying, I am using Mike Lischke's theme library.  I don't recall where I got this impression, but for some reason I thought that the themes code in later versions of Delphi was just Mike's code anyway, so I thought it might have been more of apples-to-apples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your answers.  in the end, i did this:

1. padded the beginning of the groupbox caption programmatically with spaces to the correct width.
2. move the checkbox (without a caption) into the caption area.

it's not a perfect solution but it seems ok.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to put enough space characters into the TGroupBox.Caption property. A more complicated solution would be to derive from TGroupBox and use FillRect/DrawParentBackground in the Paint method to over paint the line.

Comment: +1 @x-ray I think this is your best solution. It means that you will still get a themed background (which you want, otherwise you will get a block that doesn't fit the background), and you get a nice gap to put your checkbox into.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have just added a blank TLabel behind the checkbox.

It makes maintenance a bit of a pain though

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the Color property on the TCheckbox do it?

In your picture above, I think you can get what you want if you set the Color to same as the color of the control. That will hide the lines under the text that is part of the control and make it blend in.

Since you won't know the color in advance (due to not knowing what theme is in use) you'll want to do it dynamically at run time when the form is created, e.g.:

```
Checkbox.Color := Control.Color;
```

Comment: He can also get the white background with the code he mentioned, calling `SetWindowTheme`. The second image isn't what he wants, either. He wants the background of the check box to match the background of the group box and the group box's parent. The background of any given control is not necessarily a solid color.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I didn't quite answer that correctly. I've modified it to now suggest setting the color dynamically to the same as the control.